# Python 3 cannot find a module

Tags: python, module, installation, jupyter-notebook

I am unable to install a module called 'jieba' in Python 3 which is running in Jupyter Notebook 6.0.0. I keep getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'jieba'` after trying these methods:

```
1. import jieba
2. pip3 install jieba
```

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pip3` in the terminal is almost certainly installing your package into a different Python installation.

Rather than have you hunt around for the right installation, you can use *Python and Jupyter themselves* to ensure you are using the correct Python binary. This relies on three tricks:

- You can execute the `pip` command-line tool *as a module* by running `python -m pip ...`. This uses the `pip` module installed for the `python` command, so you don't have to verify what python installation the `pip3` command is tied to.
- You can get the path of the current Python interpreter with the [`sys.executable` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable).
- You can execute shell commands from Jupyter notebooks by prefixing the shell command with `!`, and you can insert values generated with Python code with `{expression}`

You can combine these to run `pip` (to install packages or run other commands) against the *current Python installation*, from Jupyter itself, by adding this into a cell:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip <pip command line options>
```

To install your `jieba` package, that makes:

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install jieba
```

If you are using Anaconda, then you could also install the [conda package for jieba](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/jieba); the package does not require any platform-specific dependencies or compilation, but it may be more convenient for you or necessary to install other packages that do have such requirements and have pre-compiled conda packages.

In that case, tell the `conda` command about your Python executable:

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} <package name>
```